# append data to start of NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml-parsing, nsmutablearray, feed

I have app where I am showing the latest conversation between two users.

For that I am using XML feeds data.

Let's say I have 25 rows in one XML and url goes like below.

```
www.mywebsite.com/getChat.asmx?startIndex=0
```

When I click loadMore button, the link goes like below.

```
www.mywebsite.com/getChat.asmx?startIndex=1
```

In this again I get 25 rows.

Now I have problem in displaying the data.

When I open the message, with startIndex=0, I am putting latest message at the bottom. Means I am getting data in below format.

```
4 hours ago...
3 hours ago...
2 hours ago...
44 mins ago...
etc
```

Now when I click loadmore button (startIndex=0), I am appending the XML data in my feeds (NSMutableArray). But all the new chat come to down instead of at the top.

I understand this is happening because I am appening the data at the end.

Any idea how can I append the data at the start of the feed so that the message between two users goes properly in tableview?

---

In short, I already have the data in NSMutableArray (let' say of size 20). And I want to add some data (let's say of length 10).

So new data will be at position 0-9 and old data that was there at 0-19 will get shifted to 10-29 as new data is added.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: every time  NSMutableArray alloc when he click more action

Comment: @kirtimali : nope.. If I alloc, my earlier data is gone...

Comment: If you had looked at the spec for NSMutableArray you would have seen `insertObject:atIndex:`.

Comment: @HotLicks : Thanks for your hot comments :D :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get data in NSMutableArray and reverse the objects of your Array by using below code:

```
reversedArray = [[theMutableArray reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
```

Answer (score 0):

Having a NSMutableArray:

```
 NSMutableArray * myarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

To push data at the beginning you do:

```
[myarray insertObject:myData atIndex:0];
```

**EDIT:**

To do it for two arrays (inserting several new objects at the beginning of an array) you can loop and use `insertObject:atIndex:`, you can also use `insertObjects:atIndexes:` or you can create a new array and wouldn't even need mutable arrays:

```
NSArray* dataArray;

//When new data is received in newDataArray, you can insert it at the beginning of dataArray
NSArray* newDataArray;
dataArray = [newDataArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:dataArray];
```

Comment: insertObject:atIndex will shift existing objects by one.